# Understanding how to access values in array of tables in lua

Tags: arrays, lua, nested, key

teaching myself lua and trying to work out how to access keys and values in nested tables when you have an array of them. 
If I had for example the following table:

```
local coupledNumbers = {}
local a = 10
for i = 1, 12 do
    for j = 1, 12 do
        table.insert(coupledNumbers, {ID = a, result = i*j})
        a = a + 10
    end
end
```

This loop will give me the keys (1 to 144)

```
for k, v in pairs (coupledNumbers) do
    print (k)
end
```

This loop will give me the values (something along the lines of: table: 0xc475fce7d82c60ea)

```
for k, v in pairs (coupledNumbers) do
    print (v)
end
```

My question is how do I get into the values inside the table?

how do I get ID and result. I thought something like that would work:

```
print (coupledNumbers[1].["ID"])
```

or

```
print (coupledNumbers[1].["result"])
```

But it gives an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Allister correctly put, the error is precisely in putting `.[`. But I want to add something: dot notation and bracket notation *can* do the same, but that is not always the case.

What I would like to add is that bracket notation allows you to use variables to reference fields. For example, if you have the following piece:

```
local function getComponent(color, component)
   return color[component]
end

local c = {
   cyan = 0,
   magenta = 11,
   yellow = 99,
   black = 0
}

print(getComponent(c, "yellow"))
```

You simply can't do this using dot notation. The following would always return `nil`:

```
local function getComponent(color, component)
   return color.component
end
```

That's because it would search for a field called `component` in `color` (which wouldn't exist, in this model).

So, basically, what I want to highlight is that, if you **know** the field, dot notation is fine, but, if it may vary, use brackets.

Answer (score 6):

Dot notation and bracket notation are distinct. Your error is using both of them to index one thing. (`[1].["ID"]`) The problem is the `.[`

Dot notation: `Table.a.b`

Bracket notation: `Table["a"]["b"]`

If you want to mix them, you could do `Table.a["b"]` or `Table["a"].b`

So you want to do something like `coupledNumbers[1].ID` or `coupledNumbers[1]["ID"]`

<strike>It's really just personal preference as far as I know</strike> `edit: See Pedro's answer for information on the use of variables in dot notation.`, although you can't get the *nth* item of an array with dot notation so you'll always index a number using`[n]`

Comment: Thank you guys for all your answers. This helps. If I could mark two answers as correct i would

Answer (score 1):

From L[ua 5.3 Reference Manual - 3.2 Variables](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.2)

> Square brackets are used to index a table:
>
> `var ::= prefixexp ‘[’ exp ‘]’`
>
> The syntax `var.Name` is just syntactic sugar for `var["Name"]`:
>
> `var ::= prefixexp ‘.’ Name`

You may only use the dot notation to index a table value if your table key is a literal string. Having `[` follow the dot operator doesn't make sense to the Lua interpreter as it expects a literal string.

Replace `coupledNumbers[1].["ID"]` with `coupledNumbers[1].ID`