# Understanding how to access objects in lua

Tags: lua, roblox

The closest i've gotten to figuring this out, came from this post [Understanding how to access values in array of tables in lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763296/understanding-how-to-access-values-in-array-of-tables-in-lua) which actually has the most useful information i've seen. However, I'm still running into a minor issue that I hope someone could help me make more sense of it.

As the title states, I'm trying to access an object in lua. I've learned that dot notation doesn't work, so the alternative is to use `[]` brackets. I have this object here that I can't seem to access.

```
                    [1] =  ▼  {
                       ["CopperOre"] =  ▼  {
                          ["Counter"] = 0,
                          ["Earned"] = 0
                       }
                    }
```

This was a paste from the ROBLOX studio console, for those who are familiar with it. This object can easily be seen by calling the object name `print(obj)`

However, I can't seem to access anything inside of the object. `obj.CopperOre` returns nil, same with `obj['CopperOre']`

How exactly do I access the parts of the object?

Comment: Your code suggests that the object is at index `[1]` of some other table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting to pass the index into the `obj` array to access the object stored there.

So to properly access the `CopperOre` table, you need to reference it like this :

```
print(obj[1].CopperOre)
-- or
print(obj[1]["CopperOre"])
```